# Windows Phone 7 Scoll to Grid's first element

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, grid

In my WP7 application, I have pager at the end of the page, so people can navigate prev and next.

When I call 2nd page, Grid loads with new items fine but it stays wherever user left the scroll position.

When I was using ListBox element, I achieved this like this;

```
        ListBox1.UpdateLayout();
        ListBox1.ScrollIntoView(ListBoxEntries.Items[0]);
```

but Grid object does not contain ScrollIntoView function. Is there any workaround for this problem?

Comment: `Grid`s don't scroll by themselves, so it makes sense that there's no `ScrollIntoView` method. Is your grid contained in something?

Comment: it is wrapped by ScrollViewer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can programmatically change the scroll offset of the ScrollViewer like this:

```
ScrollViewer scroll = myScrollViewer;
Double verticalOffset = 0; //0 for top, otherwise some calculated value.
scroll.ScrollToVerticalOffset(verticalOffset);
```

Comment: GridContainer.UpdateLayout();
scrollViewer1x.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(0);   
tried this, but did not work as well, just stays where ever it is.

Comment: I am certain that you are looking to change the Vertical Offset, not the Horizontal. If not, can you post your XAML?

Comment: Oh, being tired at the end of the day.. And could not even noticed difference between two. Thanks a lot!